# Create dynamic menu with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I try to create a menu with my rather weak javascript skills.

My html page looks like :

```html
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <article class="article">
      <h2>Title 1</h2>
      <h2>Title 2</h2>
      <h2>Title 3</h2>
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

My script :

```js
var allH2 = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("h2"));
var article = document.querySelector("article");

document.body.onload = addMenu;

function addMenu () {
    var menu = document.createElement("div");
    menu.setAttribute("class", "menu");

    var menu_title = document.createElement("h2");
    var title = document.createTextNode("Menu");
    menu_title.appendChild(title);

    menu.appendChild(menu_title);

    var list = document.createElement("ul");
    list.setAttribute("class", "list");

    menu.appendChild(list);

    allH2.forEach(function callback(element, index) {
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        var content = document.createTextNode(element.textContent);
        var list_element = document.createElement("li");
        var href_el = document.querySelectorAll("h2")[index].href;
        list_element.setAttribute("class", "list-element");
        link.setAttribute("href", href_el);
        link.appendChild(content);
        list_element.appendChild(link);
        list.appendChild(list_element);
    });

    document.body.insertBefore(menu, article);
}
```

The problem is that the `.href` in the `forEach` returns me `undefined` and then the links don't work.

*PS: Sorry, my English level is rather low :'c*

Comment: It may be that the `h2` elements are actually `undefined`. Did you linked the js with the `defer` attribute in the `head` of html?

Answer (score 0):

This line is going to try to fetch the link from the h2 tag which it doesn't have:

```
var href_el = document.querySelectorAll("h2")[index].href;
```

if you want to be able to click a link and scroll to that part of the page you can either use js or url fragments. I would suggest url fragments for simplicity.

A url fragment link will scroll to the item with the corresponding id (an element with `href="#thediv"` would scroll to the element with `id="thediv"`)

you could try this:

```
var href_el = '#htwo' + index;
document.querySelectorAll("h2").id = 'htwo' + index;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are trying to get the `href` attribute from the `h2` elements, but they don't have it (at least in the HTML snippet you posted).

I created a quick StackBlitz to show the problem [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-hh8hfc?file=script.js).

To solve this problem, you could add an `href` attribute to the `h2` elements, but i suggest you to prefix it with `data-href` because it is a custom attribute. [More on that here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).